# From a set of duplicate linked lights, how to make a subset of duplicated linked detached from the big set

Tags: lighting, linked-data, duplicate

I have the following setup in my scene:
30 lights on the left of the screen, 30 lights on the right of the screen. They are all linked duplicates of each other so far because their behavior is the same. However, I just realized that the 30 lights on the right are a bit deeper in the scene with respect to the camera and therefore they need to be a bit stronger.
Since their positioning took me a while, is there a way to detach those 30, make them their own duplicated instance so that I can modify their strength without affecting the 30 lights on the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all the lights on the right and *Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object & Data*, then select one of these lights, give it the settings you want, select all the other lights on the right, make sure that the modified one is active, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> *(Link/Transfer Data) > Link Object Data*.